# Rewrite rules and 301 redirects clashing in HTaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a basic rewrite rule to turn all **/pagenames/** into **index.php?page=pagename**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This works fine but I now need to redirect all the old traffic from google to the new urls. When I add the following:

```
Redirect 301 /pagename.php http://www.website.co.uk/pagename/
```

All the pages redirect to this:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/?page=pagename
```

Can somebody help me figure out why?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: *(Mention me if you think there's no valid answer.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You beter not mix mod_alias and mod_rewrite for this and handle all the rules via mod_rewrite itself for better control:

```
RewriteRule ^(pagename/?)$ http://www.website.co.uk/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ordering of these rules is of importance here.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.